# Ignore null values - Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, asp.net-web-api

How can I set up the `System.Runtime.Serialization` serializer to ignore null values?

Or do I have to use the `XmlSerializer` for that? If so, how?

(I don't want `<ecommerceflags i:nil="true"/>` tags like this to be written, if it's null then just skip it)

Comment: What type are you serializing that is null? Nullables? Strings?

Comment: Nullables. Nullable ints, doubles, decimals, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer` you need to mark the property with `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]`.

Example, the code below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SerializeToString(new Person { Name = "Alex", Age = 42, NullableId = null }));
    }

    public static string SerializeToString<T>(T instance)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, instance);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public int? NullableId { get; set; }
}
```

prints the following:

```
<Person xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApplication4" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Age>42</Age>
  <Name>Alex</Name>
</Person>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Cleanest and simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I read, you could use the Specified-Feature

```
public int? Value { get; set; }

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
public bool ValueSpecified { get { return this.Value != null; } }
```

To only write it if it's specified.

Another way would be

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
private int? value;

public int Value { get { value.GetValueOrDefault(); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it has less value (except that it makes the serialized stream shorter), you can customize your serialization to achieve this.

When using `System.Runtime.Serialization`, you can implement the `ISerializable` interface:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass: ISerializable
{
    private string stringField;
    private object objectField;

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (stringField != null)
            info.AddValue("str", stringField);

        if (objectField != null)
            info.AddValue("obj", objectField);
    }

    // the special constructor for deserializing
    private MyClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        foreach (SerializationEntry entry in info)
        {
            switch (entry.Name)
            {
                case "str":
                    stringField = (string)entry.Value;
                    break;
                case "obj":
                    objectField = entry.Value;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When using XML serialization, you can implement the `IXmlSerializable` interface to customize the output in a similar way.